# Angularjs - div ng-repeat - open model stop background scroll back to top.

Tags: angularjs

I have a div with ng-repeat. Works fine.

My question is when I have a result and scroll down on div ng-repeat results then open a model the background scrolls back to the top of the ng-repeat.

How do I stay in the current backgound ***ROW*** on the screen when I open a model window?

I am using angularjs/bootstrap.

```
   <div class="col-md-2" ng-repeat="


    $scope.viewprofile = function (view) {
       $modal.open({
       templateUrl: './views/profileview.html',
       controller: 'ProfileViewCtrl',
       resolve: {
           profileRead: function() {
          return view;
        }
      ....
```

Comment: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ -- open any modal. Nothing is scrolled. This is not problem of angular-bootstrap.

Comment: It is scrolling the background result back to the top. I am not seeing any network traffic so its not reloading the background. It is moving the background results to the first row. I open a modal on the 6th row and background goes to the 1st row. Strange.

Comment: environment. Mac - Chrome browser. I have not tested on IE or PC yet.